# calling function from PhotoGrid render function Library

Tags: function, react-native, gridview

i am using a PhotoGrid Library in react native to populate the list of photo on my apps. how to call a function from the render function ? it show [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQTNb.png) error when i call a function called "deva" on my OnPress method in `<Button onPress={()=>{this.deva()}}><Text>Bondan</Text></Button>` . here is my code...

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, WebView, TouchableOpacity, Image, Alert, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import {DrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import {Container, Header, Button, Icon, Title, Left, Body, Right, Content} from 'native-base'
import PhotoGrid from 'react-native-photo-grid'

import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen'


export default class Recomended extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { items: [],
      nama : ""
    }
  }

  goToBufetMenu(){
    this.props.navigation.navigate("BufetMenu");
  }



  componentDidMount() {
    // Build an array of 60 photos
    let items = Array.apply(null, Array(60)).map((v, i) => {
      return { id: i, src: 'http://placehold.it/200x200?text='+(i+1) }
    });
    this.setState({ items });

    //this.setState({ nama: "Bondan"});
    //this.props.navigation.navigate("BufetMenu");
  }

  deva() {
    Alert.alert('deva');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.listContainer}>
        <PhotoGrid
          data = { this.state.items }
          itemsPerRow = { 3 }
          itemMargin = { 3 }
          renderHeader = { this.renderHeader }
          renderItem = { this.renderItem }
          style={{flex:2}}

        />
    </Container>

    );

  }

  renderHeader() {
    return(
      <Button onPress={()=>{this.deva()}}><Text>Bondan</Text></Button>
    );
  }

  renderItem(item, itemSize) {
    return(

      <TouchableOpacity
        key = { item.id }
        style = {{ width: itemSize, height: itemSize }}
        onPress = { () => {
          this.deva();
        }}>
        <Image
          resizeMode = "cover"
          style = {{ flex: 1 }}
          source = {{ uri: item.src }}
        />

      <Text>{item.src}</Text>

      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}






const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: 587,
  },
  gridText: {
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontSize : 12
  },
  listContainer: {
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height - (Dimensions.get('window').height*53/100),
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loosing context of `this`. You need to either use arrow functions or bind the functions.

**Example**

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = { items: [],
    nama : ""
  };
  this.renderHeader = this.renderHeader.bind(this);
  this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
}
```

**OR**

```
renderHeader = () => {
  // rest of your code
}

renderItem = (item, itemSize) => {
  // rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either change your `deva` method definition to an arrow function -

```
deva= () => {
  Alert.alert('deva');
}
```

Or bind the `deva` method to `this` inside your constructor

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = { items: [],
    nama : ""
  }
  this.deva = this.deva.bind(this)
}
```

You get the error because when the `deva` method is invoked using `this.deva()`, the javascript runtime cannot find the property/function `deva` on the `this` it's called with (which is the anonymous callback passed to `onPress` in this case). But if you bind `this` to `deva` beforehand, the correct `this` is being searched by the javascript runtime.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, now i understand why the javascript runtime cannot find the property i made as a function. but understanding that doesn't meaning i can solve the problem because i just started with the react native environment because after i did both of the solutions its still error and keep saying that is not a function :( sorry  . .

Comment: Problem is not with the `deva` function. It is related to `renderItem` and `renderHeader`.